# Variable based on for if statement prints with extra characters (Python)

Tags: python

In the script below I am attempting to get the device name to display in a certain way based on if it's joined to a domain or if its in a workgroup.

The script for the most part works, however I get extra characters in the `devicename` variable.

The print outputs are as follows:

```
print dev_name = hostname    
print fqdn_name = hostname + domain     
print devicename = ('dev_name or fqdn_name',) - extra characters are (' ',)
print devicename should = dev_name or fqdn_name
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

```
import clr

clr.AddReference('System.Management.Automation')

from System.Management.Automation import (
PSMethod, RunspaceInvoke
)
RUNSPACE = RunspaceInvoke()

import urllib
import urllib2
import traceback
import base64
import math
import ssl
import functools

def to_ascii(s):
    # ignore non-ascii chars
    return s.encode('ascii','ignore')

def wmi(query):
    return [dict([(prop.Name, prop.Value) for prop in psobj.Properties]) for psobj in RUNSPACE.Invoke(query)]

computer_system  = wmi('Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem -Namespace "root\CIMV2"')[0] # take first
dev_name         = to_ascii(computer_system.get('Name')).upper()
fqdn_name        = to_ascii(computer_system.get('Name')).upper() + '.' + to_ascii(computer_system.get('Domain')).lower()

devicename = ''
for dmn in ['domain1', 'domain2', 'domain3']:
if dmn == to_ascii(computer_system.get('Domain')).strip():
    devicename = fqdn_name,
    break
if dmn != to_ascii(computer_system.get('Domain')).strip():
    devicename = dev_name,
print devicename
print dev_name
print fqdn_name
```

Comment: that is because you have comma at the end of devicename = fqdn_name, . Which makes it a tuple not a string. Remove the comma at the end and it will work as you want it.

Comment: Dang. Can't believe it was that simple. Thanks so much. New to posting to stackoverflow so not sure how I mark your comment as the answer.